# Could not get a resource from the pool - Error when connecting with redis docker container using Java

Tags: docker, redis, jedis

My Docker File:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  cache:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: local-redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass thisismypassword
    volumes:
      - cache:/data

volumes:
  cache:
    driver: local
```

My code to connect with the redis container:

```
JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig(); JedisPool jedisPool = new 
JedisPool(poolConfig, "http://localhost", 6379, Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, "thisismypassword");
Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
```

I still get the exception

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
> a resource from the pool

Some stackoverflow articles suggest that the redis server may not be running, which does not seem to be the case because trying to connect with the below code succeeds and I can perform any operation:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("http://localhost:6379");
jedis.auth("thisismypassword");
```

However, I do not want to do this since below constructor is deprecated

> Jedis jedis = new Jedis("http://localhost:6379");

Comment: Redis doesn't use the HTTP protocol.  Where you have `http://localhost`, is that a URL or just a host name; does using just `localhost` work better?  Where is the client code running (is it in another container)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to send the hostname or host address for the concerned parameter. `http://localhost` is neither of them. Just use `localhost` for the value of that parameter.

So,

```
JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "localhost", 6379, Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, "thisismypassword");
```